# How retrieve distinct values in RavenDb from a property of type IList<string>?

Tags: .net, list, distinct, ravendb

I have the following class stored in RavenDb:

```
public class User
{
  public string Id {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public IList<string> Phrases {get;set;} 
}
```

and I want all the distinct phrases of all users.

**Solutions 1 (not tested)**

```
session.Query<User>().SelectMany(c=>c.Educations).Distinct();
```

Do you think there will be performance issues with this approach?

**Solution 2 (tested)**
With google I found that session.Advanced.DatabaseCommands.GetTerms() is good to get distinct values of a property. But here I have a List property.
According to this:

- I create a custom Tokenizer based on CharTokenizer to split values based on a particular char (|);
- I create a custom Analyzer similar to WhiteSpaceAnalyzer;
- I create an index with "phrases = string.join("|", Phrases)" in Map, specifying my custom analyzer;
- I use session.Advanced.DatabaseCommands.GetTerms(myindexname, phrases, null, int.maxvalue).

In your opinion, which approach is better? Other better/simpler solutions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you write your index as shown below:

```
from user in docs.Users
from phrase in user.Phrases
select new { phrase }
```

Then `session.Advanced.DatabaseCommands.GetTerms()` will work and so you can use **Solution 2** without all the added complexity.

I *think* **Solution 2** will be the most efficient as it's getting the terms directly from the Lucene index, but you'll have to benchmark it to know for sure.

Comment: I also suggest to use KeywordAnalyzer; StandardAnalyzer split every single words.
Thank you.